# Error C2228 In a Simple Counter Program C++

Tags: c++

First time here, so forgive me if I'm not entirely following protocol. I will adjust as is necessary. I'm trying to make a simple program that increments (or decrements) through a counter. The counter's functions are through a class, and I'm trying to use the main for testing for functionality. I could very easily be missing something super simple, as is always the case with me, but I can't figure it out so I figured I'd ask here, since I've come here very often finding help easily. I've tried sifting through answers and nothing has been helping so far. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class counter
{
public:
    counter();
    counter(int begin, int maximum);
    void increment();
    void decrement();
    int getter();

private:
    int count;
    int max;
};

// Default constructor.
counter::counter()
{
    count = 0;
    max = 17;
}

// Constructor that allows you to put in a starting point for the counter
// and a maximum value for the counter.
counter::counter(int begin, int maximum)
{
    max = maximum;
    if (begin > maximum)
    {
        cout << "You input an invalid value to begin. Set to default.";
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        count = begin;
    }
}

// Increments counter by one. If counter would exceed max, then goes to 0.
void counter::increment()
{
    if (count == max)
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}

// Decrements counter by one. If counter we go below 0, then goes to max.
void counter::decrement()
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        count = max;
    }
    else
    {
        count--;
    }
}

// Getter for counter value.
int counter::getter()
{
    return count;
}



int main()
{
    counter test();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        test.increment();
        cout << test.getter() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The error that's appearing is:

> "dsCh2Exercise.cpp(81): error C2228: left of '.increment' must have
>   class/struct/union dsCh2Exercise.cpp(82): error C2228: left of
>   '.getter' must have class/struct/union"

Thanks ahead of time for any and all input! It's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`counter test();` declares a function named `test` that takes no arguments and returns a `counter`, not a variable named `test` that contains a `counter`. Change that line to:

```
counter test;
```

Comment: Oh wow. It seems like it was something dumb on my part after all. I've been jumping between multiple languages trying to prepare for job interviews and have been practicing basic stuff to get used to syntax.

Anyway, thank you so much I truly appreciate it.

Comment: This is a common mistake in C++, because you can use this syntax when the constructor takes arguments. It's only ambiguous with an empty argument list, and then it's parsed as a declaration.

Comment: Good to know. I'll write this down in my 'things easily overlooked' notes that I keep handy.